# Need an antonym of "Renaissance Man"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Need a word like Renaissance Man.

For example, consider there are two persons, Amber and Ed.

**Amber**:  *Amber is enlightened in all subject matter including arts, math, athletics, philosophy, music, history, and any other cultural aspect of society. She is a woman who does everything and does it well. **Amber is 21st century Renaissance Man(or Renaissance Woman).***

So, you can call Amber basically a *Renaissance Man(or Renaissance Woman)*.

But, what do I call Ed?

**Ed:** *Ed is a person who doesn't have any interest in almost all the things that life has to offer. As a result of this he doesn't have much knowledge about the world, all subject matter and any other cultural aspect of society. Even the very small number of things that unconsciously interest him, such as Gambling and putting himself in 'under the gun' situations, they eventually burn out for him. As a result most of the time even while at work he wonders if he will ever find anything interesting in this world? **Ed is 21st century ????? man.***

[???? => Looking for the Word]

**What is a word that describes Ed, just like Renaissance Man(or Renaissance Woman) describes Amber?**

Comment: ungrounded, unhinged, foot-loose, lacking focus or purpose?

Comment: Someone who is simultaneously parochial and jaded? A philistine perhaps? Though Ed sounds like a bit of a dullard to me.

Comment: If you specifically want to contrast Ed with Amber, you might be best to coin a new expression to parallel renaissance man? Dark ages man? Jurassic man? Precambrian man?

Comment: Sorry, Frosty, and to understand *Renaissance Man* is also to accept if there could never be anything like an antonym to him, that would be the figurative sense of *Neanderthal*.

Does the fact this is my first experience of *Renaissance Woman* indicate her scarcity or my ignorance, d'you think?

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions (with definitions from the OED):

**museless**:   Without learning; uncultured; (also) uninspired.

**incult**:     Of persons, their manners, etc.: Wanting in culture or refinement; inelegant, rough, coarse.

or, my choice:

**insensate**:

- Wanting in mental or moral feeling; devoid of sensibility; unaffected, unmoved; unfeeling. (Of persons, or their qualities, actions, etc.)
- Lacking sense or understanding; unintelligent, stupid, senseless, foolish.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is apples to apples comparison. For every Ed in XXI century there was a simple-minded peasant during Renaissance. Actual renaissance men were rare on per capita basis.

The thing with XXI century man, he might have advanced skills but they're usually narrow. You can go from there. Domain expert perhaps? Arrowhead man. Skills so narrow that we always need other, different specialists to create anything. Jigsaw puzzle piece man?